# Incorrect value returned by d3.mouse offset

Tags: javascript, d3.js

For some reason d3.mouse(this) is returning an incorrect value. The value it returns seems to be off by around 10px. More interestingly the values offset increases as the mouse is clicked further along the scale.

Has anyone seen any problems like this before? Any ideas what could interfere with the returned value?

My browser is set to 100% zoom.

This is really the only code i can paste.

```
  // get mouse position and use invert to get scale value for X
  layers.on('mousedown', e => {
    cursorX = xLayers.invert(d3.mouse(this)[0])
    DrawCursor()
  })
```

Comment: you be able to put a fiddle together for an example ?

Comment: @thatOneGuy no sorry as it is work code and pretty vast

Comment: We are asking for an example not the whole code. Besides whatever the language you are using ( I guess coffeescript). I think it is giving you a different "this" inside the mousedown event.

Comment: Oh that's true let me try using a standard function

Comment: I made a small fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/5s391L0x/) showing how padding can affect the mouse coordinate (try clicking the far left side). Perhaps this is causing it? If this is the issue, `d3.event.offsetX` provides the proper coordinate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whatever the language you are using ( I guess coffeescript). I think it is giving you a different "this" inside the mousedown event.